# input type file modified with separate upload button

Tags: javascript, html, file, jsp, input

Maybe my question is a duplicate, but i tried a lot of answers found around here, with no success.

On my jsp page, I have an input type file, but also an upload button, that triggers the uploading. Something like this:

```
<div id="test_form">
<input type="file" id="file" style = "position:absolute; top:-100px;">
<button id="selectFileButton">Please choose file</button>
</div>
<button id="upload">Upload selected file</button>
```

And some js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectFileButton").click(function() {
        $("#file").click();
    });
});
```

When i click on 'Please choose file' button, a new window for selection appears. But when i select the file, everything goes away, so i am now able to hit the actual 'Upload' button at all.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: `everything goes away` what is everything?

Comment: Like all the elements on the page, it shows me a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is make a div with a custom layout and place an invisible file select above it. This way the user actualy clicks the file upload. If you want to display the name of the selected file you will need some javascript though.

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: 50px;">
    <div class="button" style="position: absolute;">Click me!</div>
    <input type="file" style="float: left; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;" />
</div>
```

and some js:

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function(){
    $(this).siblings("div").eq(0).html($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: The thing is that i need the id placed on it because i do some other stuff when i hit upload. Maybe that is a problem?

Comment: you can replace 'input[type=file]' by the id of the input box, and do some more stuff in the javascript function.

Comment: okay. also, in your answer, the div class button isn't anyhow linked to the input file, so if i click on it, it won't open the choose file page.

Comment: That is the point. The input is above the div element, but it is invisible to the user. It could be the positioning isn't perfect in my example, I made the code quickly. You could add 'z-index: 999;' to the input to make sure it is on top.

Comment: I did that too, still i don't know where should i click to open that window:)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the style wasn't correct. I got it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/PdPJL/1/